# What is the difference between watcher Node and Basic Validator Node

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory, stellar-website, stellarport

[image]Can anyone explain what is the difference between watcher and basic validator node .

Answer (score 1):

Similar to bitcoin miners, a validator processes new ledgers (blocks) whereas a watcher just keeps track of what's happening in the network.

However to participate in consensus you'll also need to be trusted by other validators, so as long as nobody includes you in their quorum set, there is basically no difference between a watcher and a basic validator node other than indicating your willingness to take part in consensus.

Comment: Thank You @Sui .............